# KOMAscript - Table of content TOC without dots for sections

Tags: koma-script

I would like to have no dotted line between the sections and the page number (like for chapters). The switch I have included seem not to work (but it works for the chapter: I can have dotted lines if I set it to `true`). What is wrong?

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\KOMAoptions{paper=156mm:234mm, BCOR=8mm,twoside,
    headinclude=false, footinclude=false, 
    headings=normal,
    chapterentrydots=false,  % default
    sectionentrydot=false,
    }

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{one}
\section{oneone}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Option `sectionentrydots` is provided by class `scrartcl`, but not by the classes with chapters.

But you can use `\RedeclareSectionCommand`:

```
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  toclinefill=\hfill
]{section}
```

Example:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\KOMAoptions{paper=156mm:234mm, BCOR=8mm,twoside,
    headinclude=false, footinclude=false, 
    headings=normal,
    chapterentrydots=false,  % default
    }
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  toclinefill=\hfill
]{section}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{one}
\section{oneone}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Note that there is also `\RedeclareSectionCommands`:

```
\RedeclareSectionCommands[
  toclinefill=\hfill
]{section,subsection}
```

Then both sections and subsections do not get the dotted line in TOC.

Answer (score 3):

You can redefine the command responsible for the leaders:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\KOMAoptions{
  paper=156mm:234mm,
  BCOR=8mm,twoside,
  headinclude=false,
  footinclude=false,
  headings=normal,
}

\renewcommand\TOCLineLeaderFill[1][]{\hfill}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{one}
\section{oneone}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For finer control, you can load the `tocbasic` package (part of the KoMa-script bundle) and use `\DeclareTOCStyleEntry`.

Comment: You don't need to explicitly load `tocbasic` to use `\DeclareTOCStyleEntry`, because KOMA-Script classes already load `tocbasic`.