# ToC appearance to be customized/optimized

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, tocloft, titletoc

Unfortunately a minor problem with my ToC encountered recently. My recent research in the internet was equally unsuccessful. Thats why I ask you for help and I hope there is somebody skilled out there who may have the time to resolve this issue with/for me.

Specifically, I would like to have less space between ToC, ToT, ToF, List of Abbreviations and so on... I didn't find any simple solution to decrease the space between them without affecting the regular sections from chapter 1 and following. All in all I think it would be the best if they are formatted exactly as the regular sections in each chapter concerning the appearance in ToC (vertical spaces). By now they are handled as chapters. I forced them not to appear in bolt characters by calling e. g. \renewcommand{\listtablename}{\normalfont\rmfamily Tabellenverzeichnis}.

For illustration purposes I attached a commented picture you can find below.

In my way of thinking this will be very aesthetic after implementing the above descibed approach. If you have any concerns about my approach, please do not hesitate to suggest alternatives!

Thank you so much in advance!

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, BCOR=12mm, 12pt]{scrbook}

%%% PREAMBLE
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{setspace}   
\setstretch{1,25}

% Layout
\usepackage[
top=2.0cm,
bottom=2.5cm,
headheight=0.75cm,
headsep=1cm,
width=155mm
]{geometry}

\geometry{
bindingoffset=14mm,
%verbose,
includehead=true,
includefoot=false, 
%marginparsep=0.25cm,
%marginparwidth=1.5cm,
%showframe
}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot
\automark[chapter]{chapter}                     
\renewcommand*{\headfont}{\normalfont}
\lehead{Seite~\pagemark}                                
\rohead{Seite~\pagemark}
\renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{}
\setheadsepline{0.2pt}                              
\addtokomafont{pageheadfoot}{\footnotesize\rmfamily}        
\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{scrheadings}          

% ToC, LoF, LoT anpassen
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{titlesec,titletoc}  
\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}                                    % tocdepth
\renewcommand*{\cftchapfont}{\bfseries}                 % TOC font 
\renewcommand*{\cftsecfont}{}
\renewcommand*{\cftsubsecfont}{}
\renewcommand*{\cftsubsubsecfont}{}
%\renewcommand*{\cftchappagefont}{}
\renewcommand*{\cftsecpagefont}{}
\renewcommand*{\cftsubsecpagefont}{}
\renewcommand*{\cftsubsubsecpagefont}{}

\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\bfseries \cftdotfill{3.5}}% TOC dots 
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{3.5}}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecleader}{\cftdotfill{3.5}}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsecleader}{\cftdotfill{3.5}}
\renewcommand{\cftfigleader}{\cftdotfill{3.5}}
\renewcommand{\cfttableader}{\cftdotfill{3.5}}

\renewcommand{\cftbeforechapskip}{0.7cm}                    % TOC vertical 
\renewcommand{\cftbeforesecskip}{0.1cm}
\renewcommand{\cftbeforesubsecskip}{0.05cm}
\renewcommand{\cftbeforesubsubsecskip}{0.05cm}

\renewcommand{\cftchapnumwidth}{0.5cm}                  % TOC Indent between Number and character
\renewcommand{\cftsecnumwidth}{0.9cm}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecnumwidth}{1.2cm}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsecnumwidth}{1.5cm}

\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill{\mdseries\normalsize Seite}}
\renewcommand{\cftafterloftitle}{\hfill{\mdseries\normalsize Seite}}
\renewcommand{\cftafterlottitle}{\hfill{\mdseries\normalsize Seite}}
\renewcommand*{\cftmarktoc}{}

\renewcommand{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{15pt}
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitleskip}{-10pt}
\renewcommand{\cftbeforeloftitleskip}{7pt}
\renewcommand{\cftafterloftitleskip}{0.3cm}
\renewcommand{\cftbeforelottitleskip}{7pt}
\renewcommand{\cftafterlottitleskip}{0.3cm}

\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\fontsize{22pt}{16pt}\selectfont\sffamily\bfseries\raggedright}{\thechapter}{34pt}{}

\addtokomafont{chapter}{\large}
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\fontsize{17pt}{30pt}\bfseries}{\thesection}{25pt}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\fontsize{14pt}{14pt}\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{17pt}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[hang]{\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection}{8pt}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-10pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{12pt}{-5pt}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{8pt}{-5pt}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0pt}{8pt}{-5pt}
\titlespacing{\paragraph}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
        

% Glossary Style
\usepackage[acronym, toc, section=chapter]{glossaries}

\usepackage{glossary-super}
\setlength{\glsdescwidth}{15cm}
\newglossary[slg]{symbolslist}{syi}{syg}{Symbolverzeichnis} %create add. symbolslist
\glsaddkey{unit}{\glsentrytext{\glslabel}}{\glsentryunit}{\GLsentryunit}{\glsunit}{\Glsunit}{\GLSunit}
\glssetnoexpandfield{unit}
\glsdisablehyper

% Print Glossary
%\loadglsentries[\acronymtype]{example-glossaries-acronym}% dummy entries
\newacronym{CLIK}{CLIK}{Closed-Loop Inverse Kinematic}
\newglossaryentry{Position}{name=${P=\left[P_x, P_y, P_z\right]^T}$,
    description={Positionsvektor in x-, y- und z-Richtung},
    unit={\si{\meter}}}
    
\makeglossaries

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\begin{document}

%% Ein kleiner Abstand zu den Kapiteln im Inhaltsverzeichnis (toc)
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\vspace*{\baselineskip}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%       Inhaltsverzeichnis
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\mainmatter
\tocloftpagestyle{scrheadings}
\rmfamily % Inhaltsverzeichnis in Arial
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\rmfamily Inhaltsverzeichnis}

\fontsize{14bp}{\baselineskip}\selectfont
\begin{center}
\bfseries
\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=white] %gray!5
\centering Thesis von Maximilian Mustermann
\end{mdframed}
\end{center}
\normalsize

\ihead{Inhaltsverzeichnis}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%       Abkürzungen/Abbreviations
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{}
\ihead{Abkürzungs- und Notationsverzeichnis}
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
\setlength{\glsdescwidth}{0.82\linewidth}
\printglossary[
type=\acronymtype,
nonumberlist,               
title=Abkürzungen,
toctitle=\normalfont Abkürzungsverzeichnis,
%style=mystyle
]
%\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{-15pt}}
\cleardoublepage
    
% Notationen
\ihead{Abkürzungs- und Notationsverzeichnis}
\printglossary[
nonumberlist,
title=Notationen,
toctitle=\normalfont Notationsverzeichnis,
%style=symbunitlong
]
%\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{-15pt}}
\glsaddall
    
% ToF
\chapter*{\label{figure_index}Abbildungen}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{\normalfont\rmfamily Abbildungsverzeichnis} %\rmfamily
%\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{-4pt}}
\ihead{Abbildungsverzeichnis}
%\renewcommand{\chapter}[2]{}
\listoffigures
\cleardoublepage
    

% ToT
\chapter*{\label{table_index}Tabellen}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{\normalfont\rmfamily Tabellenverzeichnis}
%\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{-15pt}}
\ihead{Tabellenverzeichnis}
%\renewcommand{\chapter}[2]{}
\listoftables
%\cftaddtitleline{toc}{chapter}{Contents-Example}{}%
\cleardoublepage

%%% Text
\rehead{\chaptername~\thechapter}       % Reset Headers
\lohead{\headmark}
\pagenumbering{arabic}                  % Reset Page-numbering

\chapter{Example Chapter}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[2]
\chapter{Second Chapter}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Forther information}
\lipsum[2]
\section{Analysis of issues}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Problem solving process}
\lipsum[1]
\chapter{Summary}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Best regards from germany!
Max

Comment: Regarding the space between the entries: As you are using a KOMA class, you can try the class option 'listof=nochaptergap". And you have to be careful about using the package' tocloft' with KOMA classes, in my case it often lead to problems and errors, I have changed my document so that I use the inbuilt functions of KOMA instead, which works good for me. About your other regards I am unfortunately not good enough with LaTeX yet, so I can't help you there, my apologies. Greetings from Germany, too 

Comment: Thank you for your comment Lukas! 

Do anyone else have some ideas? By now it isnt solved. Unfortunately I have to submit my work within the next week!! :-(

Comment: [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/437083/244141) it is described how the get rid of the dots in between chapter names and their respective page. Regarding the package `setspace`:  your command `\setstretch{1,25}` should be equal to `\onehalfspace` if I am not mistaken. Therefore you could use `\singlespace` before your first entry (which would be your table of contents in this case) and `\onehalfspace` after the last entry (which would be your list of tables in this case)

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't solve the problem. I just tried it out. Very confusing :(

Comment: I'm sorry, but unfortunately I don't know anything else for your problem yet. If I stumble across a possible solution I'll let you know!